# How to connect asp.net core mvc application to Identity server 4?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I have configured identity server 4 service on my local machine , 
and created .net core mvc app with **No Authentication**
option ,two apps are working perfectly.

My question is there is an authentication option as **Individual user accounts**
with two options

1. Store user accounts in-app
2. Connect to an existing user store in the cloud

can i connect my identity service with applications created using 2nd option

**Connect to an existing user store in the cloud**

if can what are the parameters required in interface

[image]

if there any useful resource anyone can help about ,
it will be great help.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Just a clarifying question - do you want to use only Identity Server as authentication, or you want something else too? Your question is not very clear

Comment: Yes , i just want to do authentication and authorization .